# Remaining time based on progress?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, timer, countdown

I would like to output the time remaining for a process on the following format:

```
d hh:mm:ss
```

When the process start, it sets a `DateTime startTime`variable with the current time.

From there I have timer on my GUI that updates a label every second and here is what I have to calculated the remaining time:

```
TimeSpan timeRemaining = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).Ticks * (iProgress.Maximum - iProgress.Value) / iProgress.Value);
```

And using on the label as:

```
labelTimeRemaining.Text = timeRemaining.ToString(@"d\ hh\:mm\:ss");
```

However the time variation is displayed is going on very oddly jumping several minutes with getting into a steady mode.

I know it should jump on the begin but it should stabilize at some point right ?

I process about 1~3 records per second however the time remaining is jumping 10~20 minutes every update.

What am I doing wrong or how could I fix this issue ?

Let me know if u need more info or code.

**UPDATE**

Below is portion of the code I am using:

```
private Stopwatch _timer = new Stopwatch();
private int _total = 0;
private int _current = 0;
```

Start a thread or task with:

```
private void MyTask()
{
    _timer.Reset();
    _timer.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < _total; i++)
    {
        _current++;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    _timer.Stop();
}
```

Create a winforms Timer with the below function to run every second:

```
if (_timer.IsRunning && _current > 0)
{
    float elapsedMin = ((float)_timer.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000) / 60;
    float minLeft = (elapsedMin / _current) * (_total - _current);
    TimeSpan eta = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minLeft);
    iStatus.Text = eta.ToString(@"d\ hh\:mm\:ss");
}
```

Comment: How much is iProgress.Maximum, is iProgress ProgresBar or something else?

Comment: @Nick yes it is, Maximum vary depending on the user input which is from 10k to 10million and the most used maximum values always vary on the millions.

Comment: So lets say that you have 100K of records, and approximately 2 records per second, than your job is done after  13-14 hours? Am I right?

Comment: @Nick yes that would be correct however the 2 records per second is just a estimation of course it will vary depending on hardware and other factors for how fast a record is added.

Comment: wild guess, but could it be something with integer arithmetics?

Comment: @nrodic I thought it also, but tried and its not the case.

Comment: I suspect that this just might be fluctuation based on scale. If it jumps ~10-20 minutes over a _14 hour period_, that's only a 1.2%-2.4% jump. So when comparing to a baseline, if the _previous_ calculation was even 0.6% "slower" compared to the next calculation which was 0.6% "faster" it can result in a 10 minute jump. Similarly, I'm not sure if it would "stabilize" as it goes on as `DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)` continues to grow larger (upwards towards 14 hours) so any small changes in the progress at this point can result in large jumps of time.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I was thinking about the same thing I will give it a try on small / medium / large data sets and do some bench marking.

Comment: What if you reduced the calculation period. Instead of updating the calculation every second, try increasing it to 5 or 10 seconds. It's _plausible_ that by doing it every second (when you're averaging 2 per second) you could get jumps if the CPU causes slowdown/speedup, or it just overlaps in a period between calculations (if you do 1.5 a second, some periods you'll do 1 record, other periods you'll do 2 records).

Comment: @ChrisSinclair not much of a change, still going like before which I had something to record it or w/e so I could show it here, it going very oddly.

Comment: I just noticed that when it is able to insert 125 records avg over a second the timer looks very stable @ 600k total.

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam. Another possibility is to "smooth" out the reporting of times. For example, if your last time was "800 minutes" and your next time is "820 minutes", rather than jumping, slowly creep up the number towards the new target. See "easing" which is usually applied to animations but could be applied here to ease your number as it changes. http://gizma.com/easing/ (this page also has the math formula if you scroll down) Perhaps an "ease in/out". Doesn't even need to "ease"; you could do a linear (constant) change per second at a maximum of 1 minute per second.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair sounds interesting I will give it a try after i benchmark the current method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments you provided, when you are working with 10K to 10M records, that a fluctuation is rather big as you could see. Here is the test example that will show you the fluctuation.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Thread.Sleep(3000);
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).Ticks * (100000 - 7) / 7);
Debug.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
Thread.Sleep(1000);
ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).Ticks * (100000 - 9) / 9);
Debug.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
```

Also, even if you take care of integer division

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Thread.Sleep(3000);
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)((double)DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).Ticks * (100000.0 - 7.0) / 7.0));
Debug.WriteLine(ts.ToString());

Thread.Sleep(1000);
ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)((double)DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).Ticks * (100000.0 - 9.0) / 9.0));
Debug.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
```

But if you could normalize your records number to percents. Let's say you have 100K records, 1K is one percent and that is done in approximately 1000/2/60 around 8 minutes. After 32 minutes you will have 4% done. After another you will have 6% done and after another 24 minutes you will have around 9% done but lets say 10%. After more 30 minutes you should have 14% done. And now, if you update your textBox rarely the users will have the illusion that you really know how long it will take, and you will end up changing time for hour or two, but do it on every minute or on every percent changed (have you ever copied 30GB on Windows?)

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
dt2 = dt2.AddMinutes(32);
ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(dt2.Subtract(dt1).Ticks * (100 - 4) / 4);
Debug.WriteLine(ts.ToString());

dt2 = dt2.AddMinutes(16);
ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(dt2.Subtract(dt1).Ticks * (100 - 6) / 6);
Debug.WriteLine(ts.ToString());

dt2 = dt2.AddMinutes(24);
ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(dt2.Subtract(dt1).Ticks * (100 - 10) / 10);
Debug.WriteLine(ts.ToString());

dt2 = dt2.AddMinutes(30);
ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(dt2.Subtract(dt1).Ticks * (100 - 14) / 14);
Debug.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
```

Comment: +1 I have copied huge files but not using c# just with copy / paste but never cared to check the progress or if I have I don't recall it, nevertheless your I will give your idea a try and see how it goes I just want to have a steady estimation that can be updated with a good frequency, doesn't need to be real time but needs to reflect a more exact time